# An array of hashes -> an array of specific values

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes

```
[{"var1"=>"1", "var2" => "123", "var3" => "456" }, {"var1"=>"12", "var2" => "1234", "var3" => "4567"}, {"var1"=>"13", "var2" => "1235", "var3" => "456789"}]
```

I want to get an array of values of `var3`

```
["456", "4567", "456789"]
```

`map(& :var3)` doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map(& :var3)` will not work because there is no method `var3`, so `:var3.to_proc` will not work. Do this:

```
map{|h| h["var3"]}
```

or

```
map{|h| h.fetch("var3")}
```